# Select value from a column from a list of multiple column based on some condition SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

My table looks as follows:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 AnsString | String | 123 AnsString | String |
| String | OtherString | String | 123 TestString |
| String | 543 loremIpsum | String | String |

I am using REGEX: "[0-9]+\s.*" to detect digits followed by a space and then a string.

To compute ResultCol, I want to run regex on all 4 cols and return the value of cell where regex was a match and copy it into the resultCol.

I want the output as follows:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | ResultCol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 AnsString | String | 123 AnsString | String | 123 AnsString |
| String | OtherString | String | 123 TestString | 123 TestString |
| String | 543 loremIpsum | String | String | 543 loremIpsum |

Comment: What is your question? And why does the result column in the first row of your outcome doesn't contain the string twice although it occurs in both col1 and col3? What should happen if none of the four columns matches the regex?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: What i want was result = regexMatch(col1) or regexMatch(col2) or regexMatch(col3) or regexMatch(col4). RegexMatch gives either the the value of the column or Null if match fail. So it will look like VALUE or NULL which will stop the remaining comparisons and return the value . I am sorry I don’t know how to write it in sql. I am new in sql.

Comment: If this were pyspark, I would create a udf and apply it over 4 columns, compare the values inside the udf using regex and output the first value that matched my regex. Using this I would generate the result column but i have no idea how to go about doing this on a sql server table.